# How to prove the scalar multiplication condition if L is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Is my check for linearity a correct way ?

Comment: What is $U$ supposed to be? Also, no; you've given some specifics but haven't proven anything.

Comment: @Ed_4434 : in my opinion a vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @user1952009 I thought this too but it doesn't appear to be the case if you look at the calculations.

Comment: and for proving that $L$ is linear, simply prove that $(1,1,0)^T \times (cu)  = c ((1,1,0)^T \times u )$ for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $(1,1,0)^T \times (u+v)  = (1,1,0)^T \times u + (1,1,0)^T \times v$ for every $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3$